# (System)Verilog bit cut out from arbitrary position

Tags: slice, verilog, system-verilog

I'd like to make an output bus 1 bit shorter than the input, by cutting a bit from arbitrary position, like this:

```
module jdoodle;
    integer i;
    reg [8:0] in;
    reg [7:0] out;
    reg [3:0] idx;
    
    always @* 
    begin
        case(idx)
            0: out = in[8:1];
            1: out = {in[8:2], in[0]};
            2: out = {in[8:3], in[1:0]};
            3: out = {in[8:4], in[2:0]};
            4: out = {in[8:5], in[3:0]};
            5: out = {in[8:6], in[4:0]};
            6: out = {in[8:7], in[5:0]};
            7: out = {in[8], in[6:0]};
            default: out = in[7:0];
        endcase
    end

    initial begin
        in = 9'b010101010;
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        begin
            idx = i; #10;
            $display ("%x - %08b", idx, out);
        end
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

I found a way to write it in one line:

```
module jdoodle;
    integer i;
    reg [8:0] in;
    reg [3:0] idx;

    wire [7:0] out;
    assign out = ((in >> 1) & (16'h00ff << idx)) | (in & (16'hff00 >> (16-idx)));

    initial begin
        in = 9'b010101010;
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        begin
            idx = i; #10;
            $display ("%x - %08b", idx, out);
        end
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

But its less readable than the first, but the first is quite bad for larger buses. Is there a more elegant way to do it? Also is there standard library for verilog like std for c++, containing common modules like arbitrary rotate?

Thanks

Edit: here's the expected output:

```
0 - 01010101
1 - 01010100
2 - 01010110
3 - 01010010
4 - 01011010
5 - 01001010
6 - 01101010
7 - 00101010
8 - 10101010
```

Comment: It depends on your final goal. If you synthesize it, depending on the synthesis tool, it might produce better results with one version or another. BTW, the second one is readable enough, in particular if you add a comment about what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to work on each bit:

```
module jdoodle #(parameter INW = 'd9)
 (
  input [INW-1:0] in,
  output[INW-2:0] out,
  input [$clog2(INW)-1:0] idx
 );    
  always_comb begin
      for(int i = 0; i<INW; i++) begin
          if      (i < idx) out[i]   = in[i];
          else if (i > idx) out[i-1] = in[i];
          // do nothing if i == idx
      end
  end
endmodule
```